# How to assign different colors to splines viewable in the viewport?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, import, splines

When importing a .dxf architectural drawing I get all lines drawn in a dark green color. *(however they had been assigned unique colors in autocad)*

Is there an option to change the appearance of one or more line colors to achieve a better organized scene? *(preferably in the viewport without any additional modifiers.)*

In the past I've imported several .svg files but they always seem to turn out as a black outline in the viewport.

I wasn't able to find much documentation about this subject.

Machine specs:

Windows 8.1

Blender 2.78a

Renderer: Cycles

Comment: Not at the moment no, unfortunately. Blender doesn't have the tools to draw user customized wireframe colors per object at the moment. Future 2.8 versions might bring that. Only workaround I know at the moment is as described below by Craig D Jones, by adding a slight bevel width to the spline and using material colors instead

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Do you know if the blender foundation is adding this to a future release roadmap? 
Can't seem to find anything regarding this subject. Only this task which seems to be abandoned: https://developer.blender.org/D458
I see A LOT of potential with this extra feature. It could also help bring in more users for example 2D vector artists to manage files way better when doing laser cutting operations, etc. £
Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that if you give the curve object/spline a tiny bit of Depth, then you can set a material to it and see it in viewport. I have exaggerated the Depth here and set it to 'Full' but you can see here what is going on. If the spline does show a color in the imported material, possibly it will show after giving it some depth.[image: Curve Depth]

Comment: The best workaround so far. 
Still waiting for see if the blender foundation is going to implement this in any way to achieve much greater scene organization.